# There is an issue with my code here, can someone look?

Tags: sql, listview, vb6

I have a listview box that gets populated with five items. Here's the code that I used to populate it

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim lvwItem   As ListItem
Dim x As Integer

lvwExpenditures.ListItems.Clear
    With lvwExpenditures
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .View = lvwReport
        .LabelEdit = lvwManual
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , "FldName", "EXPENSES", 2200
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , "ID", "ID", 0
    End With


    g_strSQL = "Select FldName, ID, Label, SortOrder from  dbo.tblText_References where fldname ='expenditureitems'"
rs.Open g_strSQL, g_cnDatabase, adOpenStatic
Debug.Print g_strSQL

With rs
  Do While Not .EOF
        Set lvwItem = lvwExpenditures.ListItems.Add(, ,  .Fields("Label").Value)
        lvwItem.SubItems(1) = .Fields("ID").Value 'Populate Date column
     .MoveNext
  Loop
```

End With

Set rs = Nothing

What I'm trying to do is let the user select multiple items, concatenate the items (with a comma) and insert them into a table. Here's the code I have for trying to take the selected items and concatenate them (I built a function), but the issue is, it takes one of the items, and concatonates it three times (when three items were selected in listview). I show the label and save the ID, so the when listview is loaded the ID's go in this order 10,11,12,13,14. On my last try, I selected the top three items and the function converted it to (13,13,13). How do I fix it? I know its a small issue

```
dim x As Integer
Dim mystring As String
For x = 1 To lvwExpenditures.ListItems.Count
If lvwExpenditures.ListItems(x).Selected = True Then
    If x = 1 Then
    mystring = lvwExpenditures.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)
    Else
        mystring = mystring & "," & lvwExpenditures.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)
    End If
Else

End If
Next x
```

Comment: you are using the same reference in a loop: `lvwExpenditures.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)`  you probably want something like from your IF: `lvwExpenditures.ListItems(x).SubItems(1)`

Comment: Working. The problem i See sometimes is if I choose the middle items, (say 11,12) I see a comma before 11. So when I look in the server, it looks like this ",11,12"

Comment: Any have any idea how to work with a splitter. I'm pulling the data back from the server, trying to take the commas out, and show which items were selected in the listview. the code i have looks like this                            x = g_RS!Expenditures    fields() = split(x,","). This takes the comma out But I dont know how to make the items selected in the listview

Comment: look at your code - you are adding a leading comma all the time *unless* the first item selected is also the first in the grid.  bad logic.  maybe prepend only when `mystring.Length >0`

Comment: I just added this little if statement and it works great.                                   If Left(myString, 1) = "," Then
        myString = Right(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
    End If

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *"**Write a title that summarizes the specific problem**: The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest. So **make it count**."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim x As Integer
Dim mystring As String
dim sep as string
sep=", "

For x = 1 To lvwExpenditures.ListItems.Count
    If lvwExpenditures.ListItems(x).Selected  Then
        mystring = mystring & lvwExpenditures.ListItems(x).SubItems(1) & sep
    End If
Next x

if mystring<>"" then
    mystring=left(mystring,len(mystring)-len(sep)
end if
```

Comment: @barry17, you maybe want to accept my answer, i will appreciate that